# Different results in searching Google "site:" using a space or not?

Tags: google

Why do I get different results when I search Google for our site?

No space used.
"site:www.av-iq.com" produces 747,000 results

Space after product.
"site: www.av-iq.com" produces 17,000,000 results

Comment: That is because the `site:` directive is empty in your second example. You cannot expect them to equate. You would likely get similar results with just `www.av-iq.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, these are two *different* searches. As per the [Google help docs](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=1-636344187635762359-3325942032&p=adv_operators&hl=en-GB&rd=1):

> Don’t put spaces between the symbol or word and your search term. A search for `site:nytimes.com` will work, but `site: nytimes.com` won't.

Without the space, the `site:` operator is applied to the stated domain, so only results within that domain are returned.

Whereas, when space separated, you now have two search phrases `site:` *and* `www.example.com`. And the search clearly returns results from multiple websites, not limited to the stated domain. All sites that simply reference `www.example.com` (and many variations of) are returned in the search results.

The results are even more exaggerated when *literally* using the `example.com` domain.

- No space used: `site:www.example.com` - no results!
- Space after *operator*: `site: www.example.com` - 1,142,000,000 results.